# How to align caption left in algorithm2e?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{.}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        code\;
        \caption{I want to align this caption left}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I cannot make this caption left. Since caption package style do not affect algorithm2e, I have no idea how can I align caption left.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Changed tag "align" to "horizontal-alignment".  "align" applies to an explicit math display environment provided by `amsmath`,

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{algo}
\captionsetup[algo]{
    name=Algorithm,
    singlelinecheck=off
}
```

and

```
\begin{algorithm}
    captionof{algo}{your caption}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Please show a compilable TeX code with your solution for a fast proof ...